# Flyway: is there a way to call r-script directly from v-script?

Tags: flyway

Flyway: is there a way to call r-script directly from v-script?

I have two files r__a.sql and r__b.sql with two objects where a depends on b.

```
--v0__b.sql

CREATE TABLE b (
    rid INT
);
```

```
--r__a.sql

CREATE VIEW v_a AS 
SELECT * FROM v_b;
```

```
--r__b.sql

CREATE VIEW v_b AS 
SELECT * FROM b;
```

Because of r-s runs in abc-order - flyway raise error v_b not exists.

Is there a way to call r-script directly from v-script?
without

- adding code of view to v-script
- renaming files
- gathering views to one file and order them in file

May be any v-migration like - v1__call_r.sh / cmd / py / (any fw-meta) ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, actually you would like to order the execution of Repeatable migrations in Flyway which is currently not supported yet.